# Making a number spell program that returns a string from a function

Tags: c++, string, function

I'm very new to this and just now learning strings and I was wondering if anybody could help me finish creating this function.  I am trying to write the function so that it returns a string value but I keep getting errors when I define the function as a string.  I want to use this function in a check writing program to return the amount which will always be under 100 dollars.  My number spell function works as a void function but I want to use it as returning a string. However, I just can't seem to get the function to return the string.  Here is the code.  Thank you.

```
string spellNumber(int firstDigit, int secondDigit)
{
    string tens[] {"", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

    string teens[]{"", "eleven", "tweleve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
    string ones[]{"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    if ((firstDigit == 0) && (secondDigit == 0))
        return "zero";
    if ((secondDigit > 0) && (secondDigit<10) && (firstDigit == 0))
        return ones[secondDigit];
    if (firstDigit == 1)
        return teens[secondDigit];
    if (firstDigit >1)
        return tens[firstDigit], ones[secondDigit];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your compiler warn you about problems in this code?

Comment: Yeah, as soon I changed the function from void to returning a string and carrying in the int values I got 47 errors so I was unsure what was wrong with my code.  I just didn't know if there was something special about using a string in a function and trying to return it that I was missing or what.

Comment: "I keep getting errors". Not enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: So try something simpler; write a function that returns "hello". Once that compiles without warnings and functions perfectly, add a little complexity, test, repeat, and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, make sure you include the `std::string` header:

   ```
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;
   ```
2. You didn't declare the `string` arrays correctly. Change

   ```
   string tens[] {"", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

   string teens[]{"", "eleven", "tweleve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
   string ones[]{"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
   ```

   to

   ```
   string tens[] = {"", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

   string teens[] = {"", "eleven", "tweleve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
   string ones[] = {"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
   ```
3. And, for

   ```
   return tens[firstDigit], ones[secondDigit];
                          ^
                          |                
                    comma operator
   ```

   You're using [`comma operator`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which will always return the first one. I guess this is not what you want, change it to suit your purpose. If you want to 'add' them together, you can simply use

   ```
   return tens[firstDigit] + ones[secondDigit];
   ```

Comment: Thank you that is an error that I will address by making another string that adds these two values together and returns it.

Comment: @user3369851 If so, you can simply use `return tens[firstDigit] + ones[secondDigit];`.

Comment: I made that change, thank you, works perfectly now.  I had forgotten to define namespace std and use #include <string> in my function prototypes as well now it compiles fine.